# Excel VBA code for matching values and copying whole row

Tags: excel, vba

So I am extremely new to VBA but have to finish a project that requires sorting some data. I have two sheets. One sheet( called 'values') has a single column of values that I need to test if a value matches at least one of the 5 columns of a record (row) in another very large sheet ('sheet1'), and copy the whole record (row) to a second spreadsheet ('sheet2).

This is my pseudo code:

```
for each row in sheet1 where sheet1.row = A1:Q1231231
for each value in values  where values.value = b1:b300
    for each col (e1:j1) where sheet1.col = E-rownum : J-rownum
        if value == col-value 
            copy row to sheet2
            break, esc value 
Next row
```

And this is what i have so far, but i'm a little stuck on whether im referencing everything correctly. How do i just obtain columns E:J for each row when I need to match the values against those cells only? How do I copy the entire row if there is a match, and to immediately break and move on to the next record?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sheetrow As Range
    Dim Values As Range
    Dim cells As Range

    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Values = Worksheets("values").Rows("B2:B330")
    Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


    For Each sheetrow In Sheet1.Rows
        For Each value In Values
            For Each cell In sheetrow.cells // only need cell cols E:J
                //if value == cell
                // copy row to sheet2
                //break (no need to check the rest of the row if match)
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Just to inform, this is not for a VBA assignment. This is just a very large amount of data and a script would work better than trying to manually go through it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have some time consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for your first badge. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo-code looks good, I did remove the 3rd loop though, albeit you could certainly loop through the columns.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
     Dim i As Long
     Dim j As Long
     Dim rngValues As Range
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
     Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns of Screenupdating to let the code run faster
     Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
     Set rngValues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Range("B2:B330")
     j = 1 'counter to count up the rows on the destination sheet
     For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'determines the last row on Sheet1
         For Each rng In rngValues
             'default return value of range is the value in it, so there would be no need to use range.value
             ' _ continues the code in the next line for readability
             If Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = rng.Value or Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value Or Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value = rng.Value or _ 
             Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value = rng.Value or Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Value Or Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value = rng.Value Then
                  'This copies the entire row an parses it to destination
                  Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(j, 1)
                  j = j + 1
             End If
         Next
     Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly though.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, done much better than I approached it. Thank you!! The only thing I need to add is (the last part to my question, it was worded confusingly) that as soon as I hit the first match and it copies the row over, it simply moves on to the next row/record and starts the search again. I added an "Exit for" before the end if statement and I'm testing to see if I get the correct result.